# Google Maps v3: Given URL is not allowed by the Application Configuration

Tags: google-maps

I'm working on Google Maps v3 API, everything is ok on HTML static page you can see. But when I'm using my existing website (done by CodeIgniter) the code show me error message:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

I was setting the refferer but has no luck.